# How does one send and receive Mastercoins?

Tags: wallet, omni

I don't really understand how the Mastercoin mechanics work, do I need a special client when operating with Mastercoins? And how should I proceed with the initial investment?

If I were to recieve MCSs would I use my BTC wallet and if so how do I know the amount of MSCs in my address?

Comment: It is a good question.  The presentation, video, etc on mastercoin.org is incomprehensible.  The questions here on Stackexchange consist of a bunch of trolls voting every question down.  

Mastercoin says it is bitcoin on steroids, but there is no documentation and no exchange.  It seems rather to me like bitcoin in a wheelchair.  

An answer to this question by a non-troll would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To send or receive MSC, you only need a Bitcoin wallet when you have control over the private keys. so web wallets don't count

Comment: How so? In many web wallets you do have access to private keys.